# How to register a cordova event inside ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

How to implement below code inside the ionic

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
function onDeviceReady() {}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the help pages, take the https://stackoverflow.com/tour. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use the Ionic lifecycle events which are similar to life cycle events/hooks provided by Angular.

[image: Ionic Life cycle events]

Read more

1. https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle
2. https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks